# Escaping a number of special characters in RegEx (JS)

Tags: javascript, regex, character

I'm trying to validate password which has to contain at least

1 upper case

1 lower case

1 special character, namely one of these:    ( ) [ ] { } ? ! $ % & / = * + ~ , . ; : < > - _

Here is my code:

```
function checkForm(){

        re = /[a-z]/;
        if (!re.test(myForm.passwd1.value)) {
            alert("Error: password must contain at least one lower case letter!");
            myForm.passwd1.focus();
            return false;
        }

        re = /[A-Z]/;
        if (!re.test(myForm.passwd1.value)) {
            alert("Error: password must contain at least one uppercase letter");
            myForm.passwd1.focus();
        return false;
        }
    }
```

I would like to add another part to my code regarding special characters. How do I pack them all in a regex? Which ones do I have to escape?

Comment: accept if my answer works..

Comment: really? http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2):

You may use lookarounds.

```
^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z]).*[()\[\]{}?!$%&\/=*+~,.;:<>_-].*$
```

Comment: So... if you put everything in [ ] you don't have to escape anything anymore except for [ ] itself?

Comment: ya, but you must put `-` at the start or at the end or do escaping, since - has a special meaning inside a char class.